# For each loop won't add ArrayList String to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist, foreach

I've created a `For Each` loop, within which work is completed then added to a `String ArrayList var_CaramelChoc` to with each iteration to be added to `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> numStuff`.

But when the function is complete. These results don't show as added to the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> numStuff` (which instead shows as empty).

**How can I repair my code** so work completed within `String ArrayList var_CaramelChoc` within the forEach loop, are added to the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> numStuff` ?

**To be clear**, it is not that `ArrayLists` added to `numStuff` have no values. The problem is `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> numStuff` itself, is completed empty (no ArrayLists are currently being added).

Code below:

```
 private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> hasStuff(String line) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> numStuff = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String caramelChoc : CaramelChoc) {
        ArrayList<String> var_CaramelChoc = new ArrayList<>();
        if ((line.contains(caramelChoc.toLowerCase() + " ") || line.contains(caramelChoc + " ")) && line.contains(";")) {
            String mainString = line.toLowerCase();

            if (!(mainString.contains(","))) {
                var_CaramelChoc.add((line).replace(";", ""));
            } else {
                    ...
            }
        }
        numStuff.add(new ArrayList<>(var_CaramelChoc));
        }
  return numStuff;
    }
```

**What I am expecting to happen**, unless I'm mistaken. At each iteration, an arrayList will be added to `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> numStuff` **even if the condition below is not met** (as in either case, although the arrayList added may be empty. An empty arrayList, would still be present in numStuff). But currently this isn't the case.

```
if ((line.contains(caramelChoc.toLowerCase() + " ") || line.contains(caramelChoc + " ")) && line.contains(";")) {
```

Comment: `CaramelChoc` which we have no idea where it comes from is most likely empty.

Comment: What is "CaramelChoc"? Seems like your problem is on your **if**, can you debug your code by printing what **line** and **caramelChoc** contains?

Comment: are you sure that the first IF matches at some point ? because if the condition is never met it will just add empty var_CaramelChoc arraysLists

Comment: As @Jean has suggested, check if you `CaramelChoc` is empty. That would mean you don't enter the loop itself and `numStuff` will be empty.

Comment: Yes I have debugged and checked, hence my detailed explanation above. In regard to other comments please read final paragraph below code, as this sufficiently explains how even if the condition isn't met, an empty arraylist should be added, but it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Well, this does not really look like java style.
First, `for (String caramelChoc : **CaramelChoc**)` should not be declared with upper case, it should be `caramelChoc`.

Variables naming convention is simple camelCase. So, `var_CaramelChoc` should be replaced wih `caramelChocks`.

Based on your code, you do not need `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. Your `var_CaramelChoc` will always contain only one value, as not loop defined for adding several values. So, it can be simplified just to `ArrayList<String>`and will look like `numStuff.add(line.replaceAll(";","");`

After performing simplification of `ArrayList`, your code will become more readable. I would also suggest add `logging`, that will log current input parameter and current size if `CaramelChoc`

Comment: Although comments on my coding style could be helpful in another setting.   Your statements above, in no way solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty [[], []] at numStuff as you are creating `ArrayList<String> var_CaramelChoc = new ArrayList<>();` in the loop and empty list are getting added at the end. Initialize list only if you any element to add to it or add only if list is not empty.

The flaw lies in your if `((line.contains(caramelChoc.toLowerCase() + " ") || line.contains(caramelChoc + " ")) && line.contains(";"))`  statement. Check in eclipse debugger where its failing/passing the condition.

Any test cases?

Comment: As I have explained above, regardless whether that if statement is returned true or not. An empty array-list should be added. But currently it is not. This is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the followin approach to better debug and see what happens

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> hasStuff(String line) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> numStuff = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String caramelChoc : CaramelChoc) {
        ArrayList<String> var_CaramelChoc = new ArrayList<>();

        if ((line.contains(caramelChoc.toLowerCase() + " ") || line.contains(caramelChoc + " ")) && line.contains(";")) {
            String mainString = line.toLowerCase();

            var_CaramelChoc.add("FIRST IF") ;

            if (!(mainString.contains(","))) {
                var_CaramelChoc.add((line).replace(";", ""));
            } else {
                    ...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var_CaramelChoc.add("FIRST ELSE") ;
        }
        numStuff.add(new ArrayList<>(var_CaramelChoc));
     }
     return numStuff;
 }
```

Comment: Although I am pleased a code fix has been suggested. It does not solve anything. As in either case, **numStuff.add(new ArrayList<>(var_CaramelChoc));**, is still placed before the end of each forEach. Where it already was so the same result is incurred. (in which whether the arrayList being added, is empty or not it is not being added to numStuff.)